# How to communicate with xml file in android

Tags: android, xml, file, synchronization

My app should have capability to work online and offline.
When I have internet, I will connect to tomcat server and fetching the json object and displaying the details.

But if I don't have internet access, I want my app to work. So my idea was to store the data in xml files in mobile at some folder when my last communication done with server. Is it possible?

If so how can I do it.. Can anybody help me  ???

Comment: u just store data into ur internal memory and den u read xml file and show data through ur activity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the data in your internal memory and every time you hit the server delete the old contents.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/package-summary.html) or a database